# Obtain real Remote ADDR to peer

Tags: heroku

I use development Heroku account, and wrote simple web application. When I try to obtain `RemoteAddr` from the HTTP Request, I get IP: `10.151.38.13:47253`, which is private address, and not my IP address shown from `www.whatismyipaddress.com` for example. I understand that there is some proxy, relaying web traffic, but is it possible to get the real IP address.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get client's real IP address on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264304/get-clients-real-ip-address-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The IP address will change and can't be guaranteed.  Use a domain name.  If you really need a static IP address, check out the proximo add-on.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  OP asked whether it's possible to get the originating caller's IP address, not how to fix their own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is super old, but since it's near the top of the search result list I want to point anyone else who lands here to the correct answer.

See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264304/get-clients-real-ip-address-on-heroku) for a detailed discussion on the topic.

In short: yes, IPs can be spoofed, relayed, etc., and you should never really trust the end user.  Setting that aside, the `X-Forwarded-For` server variable will provide the best guess of the caller's IP address.  The first (left-most) address in the list ***should*** be the actual caller's IP, while the last (right-most) address in the list will be whatever IP actually connected to Heroku to make the request.  See the post I linked above for more details.

Note that using the `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable will give you the IP of ***the Heroku router that connected to your dyno***.  This might be useful, but isn't what this question is looking for.